# Is there any kind of IPv6/4 admin software that allocates IP addresses within a subnet range based on rules related to rules derived host names?

Tags: network-administration

IPv6 addresses are hard to remember, so what I'm looking for is a piece of software that after being allocated role names, classes of roles names, and subnet divisions or allocations according to the class of the roles, can allocate IP addresses for host names without knowing the exact details of the IP addresses, but can be queried to provide them.

eg. if I request a name such as `docker.webserver.proxy.doodah.001` the software will allocate an IP address or an address range for `docker.webserver.proxy.doodah` automatically, and will allocate IPs for virtual hosts or other services running on the host or the hosts in that range.

The idea is that I control the whole network, routers, switches and all, right up to BGP. Once I determine that a service needs to be provided within a particular subnet at some particular physical or virtual location, then based on the name and type of the service provided, the IP address and or range is allocated and routed accordingly, with DNS being setup as well.

I'm not interested in anything complicated. IPv6 address are too awkward to remember. All I need is a tool that allocates IP addresses from a range based on the hostname. The rules-derived host names alone should be enough, with the rule-based nature ensuring no conflicts with host name or IPs allocated.

I may not have explained myself well enough, but I'm sure software like that already exists, and there may be a package that implements it.

This seems to be question where the title seems to be clearer than the explanatory text.

Comment: This sounds backwards from the way that DHCP and DNS work in reality - to reserve an IP, one associates the preferred IP address with the MAC address (hardware address in the network adapter, or virtual equivalent), and then the computer registers itself in DNS with the IP address obtained from DHCP. -more-

Comment: -more- While it's technically possible to arrange for something that does this, you'd have to start the computer up on the network, query the connected computer's MAC address, generate the DHCP reservation for the computer in question, and then force it to reboot to come up on the newly-allocated IP address.

Comment: And if you're dealing with virtual computers running inside the computer that you've just set up, you have to do it recursively.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I have updated the question. I believe the type of software I'm looking for is called IPAM software. IP Address Management, and what I'm looking for is something that enables me to abstract away